# iphone box2d moving a body in opposite x direction

Tags: iphone, ios, box2d

I have two balls in my game. Both are affected as is by gravity (i.e. if I tilt the device right the balls roll to the right etc...).
What I want is that the second ball will be rolled in the opposite direction. (So if I tilt the device right the ball will roll to the left !)

Since gravity affects my bodies direction I cannot find a way to make the second ball roll in reverse.

What is the efficient and correct way of doing this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just use body->applyForce. Use GetLinearVelocity of bodyA and apply the opposite of it to bodyB + (gravity * -1)... (or something like that)

OR

create two worlds one with gravity set to b2Vec2(0.0f, -12.0f); and the other to b2Vec2(0.0f, 12.0f); then just do opposites in your accelerometer method to change each worlds gravity

If you are only going to ever have just two balls, option one would most likely be best.

Comment: Unfortunately both solutions are not accurate (I did not even try the second one cause it seems to waste alot of resources). I did manage to modify the Solve method which comes with Box2D using modifiers for gravity specified in the b2Body objects and it works great. Thanks for the help though